# Error Mocking a webservice with NSubstitute

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I am trying to mock a webservice object that inherits from `SoapHttpClientProtocol` and that I can't modify in my unit test. Unfortunately when I try:

```
 var myApi = Substitute.ForPartsOf<MyAPIClass>();
```

I get the following error:

> Message: Test method MyProj.Test.Business.Folder.CalendarEventServiceUnitTest.GetPerformances_WithEventsAndPerformances_CorrectlyDistinguishesThem
>   threw exception:  System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type
>   'MyNamespace.MyAPIClass'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Cannot serialize member 'System.ComponentModel.Component.Site' of type
>   'System.ComponentModel.ISite', see inner exception for more details.
>   ---> System.NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize member System.ComponentModel.Component.Site of type
>   System.ComponentModel.ISite because it is an interface.

Comment: Do not try to mock code you have no control over (3rd party code). abstract the desired behavior and encapsulate 3rd party code in your implementation of the abstraction.

Comment: @Nkosi this API is a dependency for my test. All I want to do is that when someone calls MyMethod() on the API, return a fake dataset so I'm not actually calling a service in a unit test. Isn't that a use case that should be supported by the mocking frameworks?

Comment: Not is what you are trying to mock is not mockable, which this is as you cannot modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not try to mock code you have no control over (ie. 3rd party code). Abstract the desired behavior and encapsulate 3rd party code in your implementation of the abstraction.

```
public interface IMyApiInterface {
    //...code removed for brevity
}
```

Inject the abstraction into their dependents classes. This would allow for better mocking with your unit tests and overall a more flexible/maintainable architecture.

```
var myApi = Substitute.For<IMyApiInterface>();
```

The actual implementation of the interface would encapsulate or compose the actual web service.

```
public class MyProductionAPIClass : MyAPIClass, IMyApiInterface {
    //...code removed for brevity
}
```

Do not tightly couple your code to implementation concerns that do not allow for flexible and maintainable code. Instead depend on abstractions.

Comment: I ended up following your approach.Thank you.